# nextKeyView outlet doesn't work correctly

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

As in you can see in the screenshot, I've set the `nextKeyView` outlet from field A to field B (skipping the table). Field A is the first one from the top. Field B is the one right below the table. The context menu refers to that binding.

[image]

However when I run the app, I select field A, I press TAB and it adds a new row in the table. (and field B doesn't get focus). How to avoid this?

Or at least avoid to add a row to the table?

Comment: Bindings are quite different from outlets so I made that correction.

Comment: @uchuugaka right, you are quite right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting fieldA to `initialFirstResponder` of the `NSWindow` in IB would solve this.
But doing that pragmatically doesn't work(i don't know why...).

[image]

Or setting `nextKeyView` programmatically seems to work. In that case, you don't need to set `initialFirstResponder`.

Comment: yeah it's buggy right? If it works programmatically why not in interface builder. Unfortunately the initial responder must be another field in the view. Therefore the only option is to set it programmatically, i guess.